# 3 momentary buttons controlling 3 relays

Tags: relay

I have an automotive 12V project that has 3 momentary push buttons and they all have to operate individual relays. (3-4A)

The problem is I need only 1 relay to be active at a time while toggling between 3 buttons.

I need the function of button push to disconnect other 2 relays first, so no 2 or 3 voltages cross at any time and then activate its assigned relay. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange. You should attempt to show what you have done with this project so that you can ask a specific design question. As it stands now, as written, this is in risk of getting closed.

Comment: Are you trying prevent make before break or enforce break before make or not to exceed some mA limit? Or reduce EMI or why?

Comment: There are some creative solutions to a poorly-defined requirement.  Is momentary overlap an issue? If so why when a Cap can supply that?  Is duplicate button press possible? if so then what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two very good reasons that you should use a microcontroller board to implement the logic for this.

1. You have momentary buttons and it takes a latching function to ensure that the corresponding relay for each switch stays on.
2. The logic to handle the exclusion between your three switches can be very easy to implement in the software of the microcontroller.
3. The microcontroller easily can adjust the switching dead time between relays.

The switches can very easily be implemented as low voltage directly into the microcontroller where software can then take care of debouncing the switches and implement a simple state machine that accepts the most recent switch press and only drives the singular relay coil that corresponds to that switch.

You will almost certainly require a driver circuit to buffer the microcontroller outputs that go to the relay coils. If you choose to use some off the shelf ready-made microcontroller board (arduino comes to mind) you can also find a ready made relay board that will work with the microcontroller and include the necessary buffer circuit right on the relay board.

The ready-made hardware is a great way to build up a one-off type project or to get a prototype concept proven out. If you are then actually making a production product you can then transcribe the prototype design into circuit boards of your own making to get to the desired product configuration.

Comment: Original idea was to use it (and will be using for other features) but the boot up time is not acceptable (have not looked in to power consumption yet but it seems a bad idea to run arduino/raspberry 24/7). So my options are only to redesign to 3 position switch or optimise the boot time and start controller during door unlock.

Comment: @kalakonto - You have to be joking about boot up time right? A simple microcontroller board can have current requirements in the few 10's of mA. As far as boot up time the MCU can be ready to go in such a short amount of time that the user has not yet even begun to move a finger toward the first button to press! There is absolutely nothing wrong with having an MCU run 24/7 as long as you comprehend the life of your power source, if that is a battery. and manage it properly. It really sounds like you need to step back some and think outside the box some.

Comment: I had searched for arduino and raspberry boot up times ( 3 seconds is considered really fast), i hope we are not missunderstanding each other. If running these boards 24/7 is possible i am afraid of the fire hasards still (may be irrational, not enough experiance but worryed about my car). I sure have a lot to learn but thats why im asking :)

Comment: @kalakonto - Yeah you would not want to use a rPie for this. They run an embedded Linux and they do take some time to boot up. An Arduino in my experience should not have any kind of long boot up time once you have flashed your program into it and disconnected it from the host development PC. Sure it takes time to load the Arduino development suite on the PC but that surely is not needed for the MCU board to run standalone.

Comment: Arduino with no bootloader starts practically instantaneously. Reset goes high, internal oscillator goes thru a few cycles, program starts. An 8-pin part, with power, gnd, 3 input, 3 output, is all you'd need.  Code would be simple:  if ((digitalRead(input1) == LOW) && (digitalRead(input2) == HIGH) && digitalRead(input3) == HIGH){ digitalWrite (output1), HIGH; }  3 checks: 011, 101, 110. The HIGH output drives a N-channel MOSFET (AOD508 for example) to sink current thru the relay coil. Maybe add a  little delay after a good read to energize the coil (for a minimum time?) before change allowed.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/embedded-microcontrollers/685?k=attiny&k=&pkeyword=attiny&sv=0&pv1989=0&pv1291=862&sf=1&FV=ffe002ad&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25  All can be added to the Arduino IDE for easy programming.

Answer (score 2):

He're a novel solution with no active components.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbDxEx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Three interlocked relays.*

How it works:

- RLY1 to 3 coils are rated at half supply. So for a 12 V supply, 6 V relays are used. (5 V "Arduino" relays may be easier to come by.)
- R1 to R3 resistance is equal to the relay coil resistance (or 7/5 times the 5 V coil resistance).
- When any button is pressed the associated relay is energised and latches via its own contact.
- Meanwhile, the diodes connected to that button conduct and reduce the voltage drop across the other two relay coils to 0.7 V. This will cause the other two relays to drop out and unlatch.

R1, 2 and 3 will have full voltage across them when one of the other relays is on so they must be rated adequately for power dissipation.

---

Response to AaronD's comments:

> Of course, this requires a relay with multiple contacts. The other contact(s), not shown here, power the load.

Nope. The loads can be powered from the button / contacts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2VUvm.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Loads can be connected as shown.*

> ... and it only works with DC control logic; the diodes don't work the same say with AC).

The OP specified "automotive" so this will cover most vehicles.

> The contacts shown here never see more than a diode drop across them, regardless of the power supply (unless it's just powered on and you haven't pushed a button yet) so they're not suitable at all to control a load directly.

I don't understand this comment.

> That said, I'm not convinced that a second button press will actually do anything, as it's only shorting a forward-biased diode. Is that enough to grossly change the current balance and make the circuit switch?

If RLY1 is energised then pressing B2 will forward bias D3 shorting out RLY1's coil, causing it to drop out and remove the 12 V power from R2. RLY2 will now have 6 V across it and will pick.

---

It's tough in here!

> @AnalogKid: Nothing in the circuit guarantees no cross-conduction. As above, relays open more slowly than they close, so the possibility of two relays being momentarily closed at the same time is very real.
>
> @AaronD: I'm tracing from a closed B1/RLY1, through D1, and back through RLY2's de-energized coil. Thus, the node below B2/RLY2 sees V+ minus D1's drop. Drawing current from that node risks turning RLY2 on when it's not supposed to.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcrzzA.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. In a desperate attempt to salvage his answer, @Transistor adds D7 to 9.*

Adding in D7 to 9 resolves both of these problems, I think. The buttons can't power the loads directly and the energised relay must drop out before the next one can pick. The back-feed problem is solved.

Have I missed anything else?

Comment: Of course, this requires a relay with multiple contacts.  The other contact(s), not shown here, power the load.  This stuff here is only for control, so it can be made small and low-power.  (and it only works with DC control logic; the diodes don't work the same say with AC)  The contacts shown here never see more than a diode drop across them, regardless of the power supply (unless it's just powered on and you haven't pushed a button yet) so they're not suitable at all to control a load directly.

Comment: That said, I'm not convinced that a second button press will actually do anything, as it's only shorting a forward-biased diode.  Is that enough to grossly change the current balance and make the circuit switch?

Comment: See my response in the answer.

Comment: Nothing in the circuit guarantees no cross-conduction.  As above, relays open more slowly than they close, so the possibility of two relays being momentarily closed at the same time is very real.

Comment: Ah!  Okay.  I understand the switching behavior now.  As for the contacts seeing no more than a diode drop, I'm tracing from a closed B1/RLY1, through D1, and back through RLY2's de-energized coil.  Thus, the node below B2/RLY2 sees V+ minus D1's drop.  Drawing current from that node risks turning RLY2 on when it's not supposed to.  (in the reverse direction, but it still pulls in)

Comment: Now continuing that trace, I can see current flowing through D3 and D6 as well.  Hopefully not enough to pull in their respective coils, but it's there nonetheless, and adds to R1's current, further reducing RLY1's working voltage.

Comment: @AnalogKid: See the update.

Comment: @AaronD: Have I covered everything now? See Figure 3, etc.

Comment: So a load can't turn on a relay anymore.  That's good.  (I think I still prefer the multiple-contact solution and not require these to do double-duty, but whatever)  But I don't think a button can short the other relays anymore.  That relied on B2 (for example) pulling D3 up to kill RLY1, but it can't do that anymore because of D8.  All it can do now is bring the upper terminal of RLY2 from `V+ minus D1` to `V+` itself.  I don't think that's enough to do anything.

Comment: @AaronD I don't understand that comment, I'm pretty sure the Fig 3 circuit works given correctly chosen R1-R3. If RLY1 is on then B2 is pressed, the lower terminal of RLY1's coil is raised to V+ minus a diode drop, so RLY1 turns off. Now D1 is no longer pulling up the lower terminal of RLY2's coil, so RLY2 can turn on. Have I missed something?

Comment: @nekomatic: He's changed the circuit since I said that.  D8 used to be between RLY2 and D3, and likewise for the other two channels.  Now I think it'll work, but I'd have to see it, either physically or in simulation, to be completely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Because relays, especialy DC relays with a simple diode across the coil for spike suppression, take longer to release than to pull in, driving them with nothing more than clocked latches probably will cause cross-conduction paths.

An alternative is to have three debounced switches connected to the latches such that the press transitions are OR-ed together to reset all three latches, and the release transition sets one of them individually.  For example, if the flipflops have a positive-going edge-triggered clock input and a negative-true reset input, the parts count will be minimal.

The switch press debounce time period will be longer than the relay release time, guaranteeing no cross-over.

Here are two Tyco app notes on coil suppression and relay release time.

[Relay Release Times](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=13C3311_AppNote&DocType=CS&DocLang=EN)

[Relay Reliability](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=13C3264_AppNote&DocType=CS&DocLang=EN)

EDIT:  Here is a first-pass schematic, adapted from a previous design.  The positive-true reset required an inverter.

[image]

Comment: Discharging 10uF capacitors through the switches could eventually degrade the switch contacts.

Comment: Thought about going into that level of detail; depends on the switch.  Never been a problem in my past.  Note - "first-pass".

Comment: On the other hand if not gold plated, 10uF will continually "wet" the contacts which is an excellent solution for cheap switches. +1) for the 10ms master Reset and delayed set on release in 50ms. possible could be reduced to 1ms and 5ms for button switches with smaller caps.

Comment: @MichaelKaras  I had a similar problem with P&B 30A relays that had non-gold plated 1A sense contacts for a remote SCADA system I designed in the late 70's with 96 power relays in a box.  It sounded like a gattling gun that stuck and misfired when I ran a sequential drive>sense OK, >next relay>repeat... test until I added 22uF solid Tantalums across the 10k pull-up R for TTL sensing. Wetting current needs to be 10% of rated current but perhaps 5% switched Joule rated is a better figure of merit. to break thru the oxide.

Answer (score 1):

**Design using logic gates with the switches.**

[image]

Logic gates drawn so they show the correct circuit behavior. So these symbols are correct being the Demorgan equivalent to the NAND gate symbols that you will find in the data sheet. The gates all fit within two packages because the 74HC00 has four gates in the package and the 74HC10 has three gates in the package.

Not shown here is the spare 2-input NAND gate that should have its two inputs tied to GND unless it is put to use someplace else in the system. Also not shown are the power supply pins for the gate packages. These would be the Vlogic and GND.

Comment: This looks like how I imagined the state-controlled XOR output but one can always defect this by accidentally pressing 2 buttons at the same time then an edge & State sensitive design is needed to determine who came ON first and OFF last, along with switch debounce.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - The things you mention are exactly the reason that the MCU based solution is so much better. Debouce, exclusion, multi-press, relay cycle dead time and rate throttling are all easily addressed in that type of implementation without adding heaps if extra components components to cover all the edge cases.

Comment: Of course then add EMI suppression, filters, shielding. But the USE case definitions or input specs are incomplete.

Comment: There is nothing in this circuit to guarantee that two sets of relay contacts *never* are closed at the same time.  In fact, at the gate-delay level, the currently-closed contacts always will open *after* the newly-closing contacts close, causing cross-conduction in the output circuits (whatever they are).

Comment: @AnalogKid - I agree that there is not mutual exclusion of the relays provided by this circuit. As I said above to Sunny the MCU solution that I originally proposed is the best way to achieve that rather than trying to bandaid up a circuit like that above.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be solved with 3 latches where all 3 are Reset by any of the switches by Cap discharge with bias R to opposite rail, then the trailing edge of the button press = release to clock in a 1 to edge set.

Alternative is to use any switch into OR’d to master reset and SET individual Relay after RC delay.

Comment: I need to rechearch to understand this fully but that seemes like the solition i was thinking of. Thank you and i will let you know when i figured it out

Comment: Actually this could be done without any R/C delays. You would just need a package of 74HC00 2-input nand gates and a package of 74HC10 3-input nand gates. Use these gates to make three sets of cross-coupled nand gate latches. Each latch is constructed from a 2-input gate and a 3-input gate such that it has one set input and two reset inputs. The output of the 2-input nand gates can go to resistors and the NPN transistors to drive the relay coils. Each of the three switches is setup to connect to GND when pressed and has a pullup resistor. (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) Each switch also hooks to the set input on one latch and to the reset inputs on the other two latches. Pressing any one switch activates its corresponding relay and deactivates the other two relays.

Comment: I agree By sharing 2 Resets/switch x 3 switches , shorts out all three Resets , and thus 3 switches must be Isolated Resets 3 input OR or 3 input NAND

Comment: Not according to the diagram I made here. I wonder just what you are thinking about.

Comment: I was imagining the race condition of the switch SET release and the 3 input NAND RESET being delayed by 10ns+

Comment: Do diagram here!     .

Comment: @MichaelKaras if you can write that up into an answer with a diagram, I'll upvote it

Comment: If the IOS App supported diagrams with touchscreen , I would, maybe Puffin will work. (Cloud Browser) as we wait to return to to Toronto after 2 day layover in Thunderbay from Jamaica to a post blizzard in Toronto

Comment: @nekomatic - I posted the circuit diagram with the cross coupled NAND gate latches in another answer slot.

Comment: @MichaelKaras what happens if one presses 2 switches in your case?

Answer (score 0):

MicroController design, pretty basic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBUB1B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Regarding poor fuzzy images with low resolution and high compression above using 0.13 Megpix PNG = 17 kB disk storage

Below is screen copy 1 Megpix > colour reduced from 24 bit to 1 bit then back to 24 bit since SE does not support that image format, but with max compression (9) on PNG  is only 10kB or 41% reduction.
[image]
This could be copied to EE.Meta site for further discussion.

Comment: Why do the schematics here always look kind of fuzzy?

Comment: They should not @CrossRoads but jpg is lossy so fine print gets lossy and a bit fuzzy after anti-aliasing pixel scaling which also acts as a LP filter to sharp font

Comment: It should’ve be fuzzy and certainly isn’t limited by retina resolution smart screens, but it is a site imperfection on image quality that could easily be improved without increasing site memory for the image

Comment: rather it shouldn't be fuzzy and my trick is to increase pixel size then compress more in .png or jpg instead of default compression ratio

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate version of my previous schematic.  It turns out that there is no need for three debouncing capacitors.  C1 now debounces all three switches.

Note - I'm posting this as a separate answer so the previous schematic remains available.

[image]